# Determining currently-serving files in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, logging, connections

serverfault showed me [this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/86183/how-to-tell-what-requests-apache-is-currently-serving), and I think I want to do the same thing, but in IIS, not Apache.

I have a "dashboard" application I'm building and I want it to show what files are currently being served by IIS. They'll mostly all be large files.

I believe that the ILogScripting COM Interface would have been one good place to start, but it's not available in IIS 7, and it relies on the underlying IIS logs for its data. And therein, I believe, lies my problem.

How do I make IIS put in, essentially, two log entries, one as the request begins, and one when the connection is closed?

Also, it looks like IIS doesn't "commit" log entries as they're occuring, in "real-time". There's some kind of delay/batch-job. That will cause a problem for me too.

Or do I need to do something in isapi instead?

Answer (score 1):

IIS7 Has a built in [request monitoring module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732518(WS.10).aspx) that can be accessed via WMI.